# python3 encode replace unicode characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

According to the documentation, the following command

```
'Brückenspinne'.encode("utf-8",errors='replace')
```

should give me the byte sequence`b'Br??ckenspinne'`.  However, unicode characters are not replaced but encoded nevertheless:

```
b'Br\xc3\xbcckenspinne'
```

Can you tell me how I actually eliminate Unicode characters? (I use replace for testing purposes, I intend to use `'xmlcharrefreplace'` later.  To be totally honest, I want to convert the unicode characters to their xmlcharref, keeping everything as a string).

Comment: You are clearly misunderstanding the documentation. Perhaps you could belatedly [edit] to explain why you expected that behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`utf-8` encoding can represent the character `ü`; there is no error, so no replacement occurs.

To see `errors='replace'` in action, use another encoding that cannot represent the character. For example `ascii`:

```
>>> 'Brückenspinne'.encode("ascii", errors='replace')
b'Br?ckenspinne'

>>> 'Brückenspinne'.encode("ascii", errors='xmlcharrefreplace')
b'Br&#252;ckenspinne'
```